# How to partition high cardinality data that is extended daily?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have an Athena table like this:

`values_by_time`:

- Columns:

  - `id` string (contains UUIDs)
  - `value` string
  - `created` timestamp (this is a partition key)
- Partition: `[created]`

But I want to query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM values_by_time WHERE id = 'ac09b809-471e-4296-b99b-e57408075609'
```

So my partition by `[created]` is inefficient.

I [read that bucketing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-dynamic-id-partitioning.html) can be used for high cardinality columns, such as my `id`:

`values_by_id`:

- Columns:

  - `id` string (bucket by this)
  - `created` timestamp
  - `value` string
- Bucket By: `[id]`

This makes the look-up efficient:

```sql
SELECT * FROM values_by_id WHERE id = 'ac09b809-471e-4296-b99b-e57408075609'
```

However, I cannot do an `INSERT INTO` on a table with bucketing! This means that I cannot add new data to it after table creation. Creating the table fresh every day seems inefficient too.

How should I arrange my Athena table so that:

1. I can efficiently query by `id`
2. I can insert new data every day

Comment: Using bucketing won't help in your use case. Is it possible to add the `between and` condition using created column along with your where id condition? This would limit the data scan for your query. You can also try using compression techniques while storing your data. Your current partition strategy is correct. Please check following article  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

Comment: @SwapnilKhante Why wouldn't bucketing help in this case?